# Find substring of a string in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file :

```
(000002) 15-11-2012 09:04:04 - 2009031 (172.27.16.154)> 230 Logged on
(000003) 15-11-2012 09:04:19 - 2009032 (172.27.16.154)> 230 Logged on
(000262) 15-11-2012 11:47:53 - cs307 (172.27.23.59)> 230 Logged on
```

and many more entries like this.

I just need output as :

```
2009031
2009032
cs307
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '$0=$5'
```

Result

```
2009031
2009032
cs307
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
awk -F " " '{print $4}' file.txt
```